# VLC RTSP stream of two input video streams - command line problems

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I'm trying to create an **overlay of two security camera** views onto one video stream, and streaming it out as **RTSP** protocol. There are two IP camera streams on input, and only one video stream combining both views in overlay - as output.

To create overlay effect and to stream video out, I use **VLC player v3.0.6** on Windows 10. I run it from command line to setup everything (correct overlay, accepting input streams and creating output stream). I can receive my inputs and create overlay, and then either display it on screen, or stream it out using http protocol. **HTTP steam works great**, I can open it on another computer and watch it. Hovewer I cannot change output from HTTP to RTSP and make it work.

This is a VLM config file, setting inputs and outputs. This one outputs HTTP stream.

```
del all

new channel1 broadcast enabled                                                  
setup channel1 input rtsp://xxx:xxx@192.168.xx.xx/profile2/media.smp
setup channel1 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=1,height=720},select=video}                                                                                                                                                                                         

new channel2 broadcast enabled 
setup channel2 input rtsp://xxx:xxx@192.168.x.x/profile2/media.smp
setup channel2 output #duplicate{dst=mosaic-bridge{id=4,height=340},select=video}        

new background broadcast enabled
setup background input "file:///C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\pic.jpg"
setup background option image-duration=-1
setup background option image-fps=10
setup background option mosaic-width=1280
setup background option mosaic-height=720
setup background option mosaic-keep-picture=1   


setup background output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic,vcodec=mpeg,vb=2000,fps=10}:bridge-in{delay=0,id-offset=0}:standard{access=http,mux=ogg,dst=192.168.xx.xx:18554}

control channel1 play
control channel2 play
control background play
```

To run it, I call VLC using this command:

```
vlc "--vlm-conf=C:\Projekty\mosaic\mosaic4.vlm" "--clock-jitter=0" "--mosaic-width=1280" "--mosaic-height=720" "--mosaic-keep-picture" "--mosaic-row=2" "--mosaic-cols=2" "--mosaic-position=1" "--mosaic-order=1,2,3,4" "--ttl=12" "--udp-caching=800" --verbose=2
```

It sets the mosaic view and resolution.

Now, the problem lies in the VLM file, when setting output. I use :standard module for output, but this module doesn't support RTSP.

Ok, let's try and let VLC configure everything for me. There is option of streaming using regular VLC GUI. You choose what to steam (file/your screen/single input stream), then you choose output format, and that's it. At the end of process, VLC even shows you the commands it uses to stream. It looks like this:

```
:sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=56,venc=x264{profile=baseline},fps=12,scale=Automaticky,width=176,height=144,acodec=mp3,ab=24,channels=1,samplerate=44100,scodec=none}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/} :no-sout-all :sout-keep
```

It's a bunch of video transcoding settings, and then the output - **:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}** . But it works great, the other side receives working RTSP stream.

Naturally, I try to replace my :standard(http) module with this :rtp setting, but for some reason, it just doesn't work - the other side can't open stream.

```
setup background output #transcode{sfilter=mosaic,vcodec=mpeg,vb=2000,fps=10}:bridge-in{delay=0,id-offset=0}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/} :no-sout-all :sout-keep
```

Any suggestions? I can receive my streams, I can merge them together, I just can't get them out. VLC documentation doesn't help much at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you share logs?